# GGPLOT X-AXIS values refer to DATE (M/Y)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have this problem everytime I need to work with this I have the same problem, sometimes I can solve it, this time I'm not getting.

### Dataset (EXAMPLE):

| ID | DATE | PZ | subst.1 | susbt.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 01-12-99 | 1 | 10 | 62 |
| id1 | 01-02-00 | 2 | 46 | 25 |
| id2 | 01-12-99 | 3 | 81 | 5 |
| id2 | 01-02-00 | 4 | 32 | 1 |
| id3 | 01-12-99 | 3 | 41 | 8 |
| id3 | 01-02-00 | 3 | 2 | 15 |

### OBJECTIVE:

Using ggplot I need to make n plots for *n* substances, the values to be plotted are DATE VS subst.*n* grouped by PZ, like:

```
Plot1<-ggplot(data=EXAMPLE, mapping = aes(x=Date, y=susbt.1, color=PZ, group=PZ))
```

The problem is the dates shown in the x-axis aren't ordered (I want it to show older>>>recent) and aren't shown in format MM/YY, reasonably since it wasn't command to.

### Tried solution 1#

making variable DATE as factor, then altering the different levels like:

```
as.factor(data$date)
levels(data$date)=c("DEZ-99","FEB-00")
```

Didn't work, in fact when I tried to confirm if the variable date was a factor w/ is.factor() it said FALSE. Don't know why.

### Tried solution 2#

Was trying making the variable Date as Date forma

```
#data$Date<-as.Date(data$Date, format = "%d - %m - %y")
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't show every value in x for all values.
I read that would be easier to make date as factor, because it show every value, so I tried the solution 1#.

## FULL CODE

```
data<-read.csv('file.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ',');
data
head(data)

class(data$Date)
#data$Data<-as.Date(data$Date, format = "%d - %m - %y")

data1<-data[-c(1:5),]; #erase lines affect to id 1
data1

data2<-data1[-c(21:25),]; #erase lines affect to id 6
data2

as.factor(data2$Date)
levels(data2$Date)<-c("Jan-21", "April-20", "Jul-20", "Oct-19","Oct-20" )
levels(data2$Date)

library(ggplot2,gridExtra)


#every except id 1 and 6

PAH<-ggplot(data=data2, mapping = aes(x=Date, y=PH, color=PZ,group=PZ))+geom_point()+geom_line();
PAH<-PAH+labs(title = 'Ev.', x= 'month', y='PH (ug/l)', color='Pz');
PAH
```

Thanks a lot for reading,

Comment: Try the following to convert DATE to date: `df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE, format = "%m-%d-%y")` (remove spaces around hyphens). I think that should be all that is necessary to plot in order on the x-axis.

Comment: @WillOldham, it doesn't work because when you plot the data that way the x-axis with date format just shows the equal distant dates and not every single value of x that has a value of y. Or maybe adding x_scale function with breaks=months may work, will try it! But for now I posted a new comment saying it is solved i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution #1 would work, but has a bug. You need to assign the `as.factor`, i.e.

```
data$dateFactor <- as.factor(data$date)
levels(data$dateFactor)  <- c("DEZ-99","FEB-00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys yes thank you for reading.
After posting, I saw my error, corrected solved the problem with the factor issue.
Solved then the other problem by ordering the levels. By doing data$date <- factor(data$date, c( "DEZ-99", "FEV-00)).

I have trouble to understand how reordering levels doesnt overwrite the data, like how does R knows that the initial rows assigned with ordering facto X, Y and then ordering Y and X doens't overright the data that was initial assigned with X.

Probably I wasn't clear, but well it worked!
I will think about what I don't understand and try to ask here.

Thanks a lot to everyone